# Play! - GET /user/{id} without Password

Tags: java, rest, playframework, playframework-2.0

For my Play! Application I have a User.class

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

@Id
public String email;
public String name;
public String password;

public User(String email, String name, String password) {
  this.email = email;
  this.name = name;
  this.password = password;
}

...
}
```

Everytime I ask on /user/{id}.json for a user object, I want to prevent that the password string is sent. How to do that? Is that the normal use case or is there another way to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play uses [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to serialize to Json, therefore all the Jackson tools are available.

To exclude a field from the Json serialization, you can annotate it with the `@JsonIgnore` annotation.

In your example :

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    public String email;
    public String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    public String password;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thats what I searched for. Is there a similar annotation for XML?

Comment: I don't think there is something provided by Play to generate XML. Do you already have some code that generates XML ?

Comment: @mguillermin And what is the problem with XML generation?

Comment: There is no problem with XML generation. We just need to know how the XML is serialized (JAXB, XStream, ...?) to be able to give specific information on how to exclude fields.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using dummy class for your json?

Like this..
This is your model for User

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model 
    {

     @Id
     public String email;
     public String name;
     public String password;

     public User(String email, String name, String password) {
     this.email = email;
     this.name = name;
     this.password = password;
    }
}
```

This will be your Dummy class for returning json value

```
public class UserDummy 
    {
     public String email;
     public String name;

     public UserDummy(string email) {
     models.User user = models.User.findById(email);
     this.email = user.email;
     this.name = user.name;
    }
}
```